# How to generate model with restriction on data precision, scale in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I am trying to generate the following a model named `PriceUsdOneMinIntervals`, but unable to apply the format for precision and scale correctly, can someone please advise how to correct the syntax in the following:

```
rails generate model PriceUsdOneMinInterval unix_timestamp:integer usd_high:decimal :precision[20] :scale[8] usd_low:decimal :precision[20] :scale[8] usd_open:decimal :precision[20] :scale[8] usd_close:decimal :precision[20] scale[8]
```

I have referred to [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column) api while making the above statement.

Comment: `rails generate model --help` should help ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRy this

```
rails generate model PriceUsdOneMinInterval :unix_timestamp, :integer, 
:usd_high, :decimal, precision: 20, scale: 8, :usd_low, :decimal, precision: 20, 
scale: 8, :usd_open, :decimal, precision: 20, scale: 8, 
:usd_close, :decimal, precision: 20, scale: 8
```

OR

generate migration with just field names and data_types and then change you can change the values in migration

```
def change
    add_column :price_usd_one_min_intervals, :unix_timestamp, :integer
    add_column :price_usd_one_min_intervals, :usd_high, :decimal, precision: 20, :scale: 8
    add_column :price_usd_one_min_intervals, :usd_low, :decimal, precision: 20, scale: 8
    add_column :price_usd_one_min_intervals, :usd_open, :decimal, precision: 20, scale: 8
    add_column :price_usd_one_min_intervals, :usd_close, :decimal, precision: 20, scale: 8
end
```

Comment: believe you're missing some commas in the first block of code. I got by with the second one though, where you modify the file after generating a model

Answer (score 0):

```
rails g model PriceUsdOneMinInterval \
unix_timestamp:integer \
'usd_high:decimal{20,8}' \
'usd_low:decimal{20,8}' \
'usd_open:decimal{20,8}' \
'usd_close:decimal{20,8}'
```